# How to match line type with legend?

Tags: r, visualization, echarts4r

How can the line types in the chart match with the legend?

```
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(50),
  y = rnorm(50, 10, 3),
  z = rnorm(50, 10, 3)
)

df %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_line(y, showSymbol = FALSE, lineStyle = list(type = "dashed")) %>%
  e_line(z, showSymbol = FALSE, lineStyle = list(type = "dotted"))
```

In the output, the legend shows line with a circle - it would be better if it showed the actual line types, or at least not have the circles, such as: -- -- -- y, - - - - z

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the legend cannot match the linetype: https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/188

Comment: it is solved now